# Big O notation for fib recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, fibonacci

What is the Big-O run-time of the following function?  Explain.

```
static int fib(int n){
  if (n <= 2)
     return 1;
  else 
     return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
   }
```

Also how would you re-write the fib(int n) function with a faster Big-O run-time iteratively?
would this be the best way with O(n):

```
 public static int fibonacci (int n){
 int previous = -1;
 int result = 1;
 for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
 {
 int sum = result + previous;
 previous = result;
 result = sum;
 }
 return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Solve for T(n) in T(n) = c + T(n-1) + T(n-2).

Comment: T(n)= T(n-1) + T(n-2) + O(1)
T(n)= O(2^n-1) + O(2^n-2) + O(1) = O(2^n)
is what i have.  Just double checking myself

Comment: Just trying to gain a full understanding of using the Big O and recursion.

Comment: Big O and recursion are not language-specific, so this is not really a java question.

Comment: This is a bit late since someone already gave the answer and it was accepted but it's generally bad to just state the problem and ask for an answer. It would be better if you state the problem then tell us what solution you have so far and exactly what you're unsure of. (I think that second code snippet might be your work, so my comment is mostly targeted at the first part of your question)

Comment: @GeorgeDenver - [the homework tag is deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?cb=1), but it does smell like an assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Proof**

You model the time function to calculate `Fib(n)` as sum of time to calculate `Fib(n-1)` plus the time to calculate `Fib(n-2)` plus the time to add them together (`O(1)`).

`T(n<=1) = O(1)`

`T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + O(1)`

You solve this recurrence relation (using generating functions, for instance) and you'll end up with the answer.

Alternatively, you can draw the recursion tree, which will have depth `n` and intuitively figure out that this function is asymptotically `O(2`<sup>`n`</sup>`)`. You can then prove your conjecture by induction.

Base: `n = 1` is obvious

Assume `T(n-1) = O(2`<sup>`n-1`</sup>`)`, *therefore*

`T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + O(1)` *which is equal to*

`T(n) = O(2`<sup>`n-1`</sup>`) + O(2`<sup>`n-2`</sup>`) + O(1) = O(2`<sup>`n`</sup>`)`

**Iterative version**

*Note that even this implementation is only suitable for small values of n, since the Fibonacci function grows exponentially and 32-bit signed Java integers can only hold the first 46 Fibonacci numbers*

```
int prev1=0, prev2=1;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  int savePrev1 = prev1;
  prev1 = prev2;
  prev2 = savePrev1 + prev2;
}
return prev1;
```

Comment: exactly what i had. awesome.  thanks for the help.  just wanted to double check.